# Confusing Unable to open PDO connection Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, pdo, database-connection, propel

I have confusing problem with PDO connection to MySQL. Webapplication written in PHP generating that error:

```
exception 'PropelException' with message 'Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.xxx.xxx' (4)]' in ./lib/symfony/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/Propel.php:610
```

It is confusing because max_connections limit wasn't reached:

```
MAX CONNECTIONS
Current max_connections = 1000
Current threads_connected = 8
Historic max_used_connections = 783
The number of used connections is 78% of the configured maximum.
Your max_connections variable seems to be fine.
```

Also at the same time, when I get this error, other webaplication (without propel) or command line tool can connect to MySQL very well.

Additional details:

- MySQL 5.5.30
- PHP 5.3.23
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you have to google on the original error message ("[2003] Can't connect to MySQL server" one) and then verify all connection credentials.

Comment: Connection credentials are ok, because Webapplication is working. But at random date/time I get this error for 5 - 10 minutes. PHP (propel) can't connect to MySQL, but a the same time I can connect.

Comment: that's quite important detail about 5-10 minutes. I'd bet on some network problems.

Comment: It might be. I have noticed that at the same time internal traffic is near 100MBit switch limit. I will trace this. Thanks.